# why do not we shift this way?

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, knuth-morris-pratt

While studying *Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm* for a string :

```
ABC ABCDAB ABCDAB
```

for a pattern :

```
ABCDABD
```

I am stuck on one step. I will highlight the step where I am currently stuck.

```
ABC ABCDAB ABCDAB
ABCDABD

ABC ABCDAB ABCDAB
   ABCDABD

ABC ABCDAB ABCDAB
    ABCDABD

ABC ABCDAB ABCDAB
        ABCDABD--------------------(WHY THIS ?)
```

I do not understand the above step. I expect the above step to be :

```
ABC ABCDAB ABCDAB
          ABCDABD
```

Please explain the logic/reason for the 'right' step.

Comment: The second AB in the pattern matched , so we shift such that the first AB is now where the second one was. Why do you think we can shift any farther?

Comment: @n.m. can you tell me the criteria to look up while working with _knuth morris_ algo. I don't understand it completely, though I tried reading the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

When ' ' compare with 'D' it find mismatch. And this algorithm 'remember' that the previous "AB" is compared, so it need to check if the mismatched character is 'C' .

The idea of the KMP method is explained in the book 'Introduction to  Algorithms'. It is very similar to the infinite state machine method, which may help you to understand it.